# Is there a way to specialize a templated function to discriminate when the type of an argument is a pointer from when it is not?

Tags: c++, pointers, templates, specialization

Let's consider those templated functions

```cpp
template <typename T> void Func(T* p)
{
  printf("pointer ");
  Func(*p);
}

template <typename T> void Func(T)
{
  printf("type");
}
```

I want to write them so that if I give an arguments with several pointers type to it, the function specialized with the pointer type is recursively called to the point where there is no pointer anymore and finally the function without pointer is called.
Typically, if I write

```cpp
int a;
int* a2 = &a;
int** a3 = &a2;
int*** a4 = &a3;
Func(a4);
```

I want the output to write

```
pointer pointer pointer type
```

Unfortunately if I write it that way, all that I ever get is the call to the non-pointer function.

Is there any way to achieve that ?

Comment: In C++17, you can get rid of one overload altogether and just have `Func(T)` that uses `if constexpr` with `std::is_pointer` to test if `T` is a pointer or not, eg: `template <typename T> void Func(T param) { if constexpr (std::is_pointer_v<T>) { printf("pointer "); Func(*p); } else { printf("type"); }`  See [Simplifying templates and #ifdefs with if constexpr](https://blog.tartanllama.xyz/if-constexpr/), which has examples similar to yours.

Comment: Notice that it is overload, not specialization.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just need to swap the functions around.  In `template <typename T> void Func(T* p)` when you do `Func(*p);` all the compiler knows about is `template <typename T> void Func(T* p)`.  So you wind up calling the same function recursively until it errors when you no longer have a pointer.  If you use

```
template <typename T> void Func(T)
{
  printf("type");
}

template <typename T> void Func(T* p)
{
  printf("pointer ");
  Func(*p);
}
```

then when you call `Func(*p);` the compiler knows about `template <typename T> void Func(T)` and will call when you no longer have a pointer giving you

```
pointer pointer pointer type
```

Comment: To the OP. Even with this, you can't use `int*** a;
Func(a);` You have to initialize `a` to be valid pointer. Otherwise, `Func(*p)` will cause undefined behavior.

Comment: I hadn't thought about the importance of declaration order. It's a little bit counter intuitive but I believe it makes sense, thanks a lot !